# load files dynamically in Master page based on appsettings key

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

If I want to add a link to a file in the master page, I put it into
appsettings.config like this, inside

```
<appSettings> 
<add key="key1" value="filepath/filename.filextension" />
...
</appSettings>
```

and then in the Master file, Master1.Master.cs
in the **OnInit** method:

```
string s1 = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key1"];
```

The outcome should be that the value is added inside Master1.Master
in the `<head>` tag.
Am I configuring this correctly? Something goes wrong and the links are not added (checked html source after deploy).
I am doing it like this because I want to specify this URL dynamically with my deploy tool depending on the environment I deploy to.
I am using Visual Studio 2013 with C# and ASP.NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```cs
string s1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key1"];`
```

Just remember to reference the System.Configuration Assembly in your project.